# Triangle with white border

Tags: html, css

How can I create Triangle with white border using CSS? Like the image below.

[image]

when i add this css

```
.triangle {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 20px solid white; 
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    position:relative;

}
.triangle:before {
    content:'';
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 10px solid red; 
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;
    left:-17px;
}
```

result is

[image]

Comment: I'm excited to see if anyone can pull this off.

Comment: Add your code please. It is an interesting question but no one would start from scratch.

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/6vNTN/

Comment: Use SVN for this; CSS really isn't the right tool for spot graphics.

Comment: @Spudley You mean SVG?

Comment: @IgorJerosimić - yep, SVG. that'll be a typo.  :)

Comment: well, nobody liked my work? Although i thought you all will :D Due to upvotes and marked favorites on this question.

Comment: Copying code from an answer just to go on is not too elegant. You can comment on answers to ask for more details.

Comment: @qben are you saying this to me? Man, you were not born with knowledge of all that stuff. OK. You also learnt it from somewhere. I also learnt how to code. And well, this a kid work no need of copying answers like you. I just used `:before` psuedo class.

Comment: @AspiringAqib I said it to the questioner. Don't you realize your code is in the question now?

Comment: @qben Then clarify! I got hyper because i done major work on it. Well, you commented just after my comment. So, i didn't realize it that it is for OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
.triangle {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 20px solid white; 
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    position:relative;

}
.triangle:before {
    content:'';
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 10px solid red; 
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;
    left:-17px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dp5Cu/4/)

Comment: let me check because i made it in FF. Firefox add kinda greyish border by its own and chrome does not show this behaviour. So, white border is not visible.

Comment: Actually it works, I just didn't see it because of white border on white background :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dp5Cu/3/ hey man it is better :D well read my first comment on this answer.